# In R, excel COUNTA equivalent, or another way to calculate averages in "char" columns?

Tags: r, excel

I have a spreadsheet where some of the values are entered as "N/A", and some of the cells are blank.

| joe | pete | mark | Average ⬇️ (the average per row) |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 85 | N/A | 87.5 |  |
| N/A |  | 92 | 92 |  |
| 88 | 90 |  | 89 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | **<-- This row Counts all non-blank values in each column** |

I want to import these into R to do two things:

- Get an average of these values for each row across multiple columns and
- get a count of the values per column (see below for example)

The problem is: I want to be able to count all the non-blank cells (including those with "N/A" values, as they are actually important part of the data and are different from blanks

**What I tried:**
Replaced the "N/A" values in Excel before I imported into R by changing the "n/a"s to 0's, so I can import the columns as numbers,  but the problem is, then my averages are messed up. If I add a 0 to the first row, for example, then my average is 58.33 (90+85+0)/3 = 58.33
That is not what I want. I want an average of only those that are not "N/A".

The other issue I have, is that if I leave those as N/A, then I can get a count, but my columns are not numeric anymore and I can't perform an average calculaiton.

I know I can do this easily in excel with =COUNTA and =AVERAGE, but I would prefer to do as much wrangling as possible in R.
Any suggesitons??

Thanks!!

Comment: If that's an R data.frame, do you realize that your columns are not numeric?

Comment: Further, why do you have no mean for row 3 (it has a blank) but row 2 has a mean (has both a blank and an `NA`)?

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I had made an error on the mean in row 3 that I have corrected now.
Regarding the first comment, this would be what my spreadsheet would look like and what I want to achieve. As I described, the problem I have is that if I replace all "N/A" with a numeric value (like 0 for example), then my average is off, if I don't, then I can't calcuate the mean. Is there a way to do both?

Comment: Have you discarded this question? You are unlikely to get additional answers or fix the existing ones unless you provide clearer logic and update your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. The `na.rm=TRUE` should be what you want:

```
example_data = c(90, 85, NA)
MEAN = mean(example_data, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

### base R

```r
dat$avg <- mapply(function(...) {
  dots <- unlist(list(...))
  mean(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(dots[nzchar(dots)])),
       na.rm = TRUE)
}, dat$joe, dat$pete, dat$mark)
dat
#   joe pete mark  avg
# 1  90   85 <NA> 87.5
# 2  NA        92 92.0
# 3  88   90      89.0
as.data.frame(lapply(dat, function(z) sum(nzchar(z))))
#   joe pete mark avg
# 1   3    2    2   3
dat <- rbind(dat, as.data.frame(lapply(dat, function(z) sum(nzchar(z)))))
dat
#   joe pete mark  avg
# 1  90   85 <NA> 87.5
# 2  NA        92 92.0
# 3  88   90      89.0
# 4   3    2    2  3.0
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(joe = c(90, NA, 88), pete = c("85", "", "90"), mark = c(NA, "92", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I tried both solutions, but when the N/As are changed to zeros in the data frame, the averages are not accurate because the mean takes 0 into account and averages the other values with the zero. Since I am not good with R at this point I am planning to import the csv twice in my R script, one as characters and use that to count non blanks (numbers and N/As) and import it again with the N/As replaced by blanks so I can calculate the averages. Thanks for offering solutions!!! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: You should communicate your needs (and constraints) better, that can be done easily. I suggest you update your question with clearer rules, and change your sample data (and expected output) to challenge each of the rules.